# I don't know why this two-liner works

Tags: c++

```
int countMatches(vector<vector<string>>& items, string ruleKey, string ruleValue) {
    int idx = ruleKey == "type" ? 0 : ruleKey == "color" ? 1 : 2, res = 0;
    return count_if(begin(items), end(items), [&](const auto &i) { return i[idx] == ruleValue; });
}
```

This is a problem off of leetcode. I attached the link below.

I will try and say what I think is going on, if anything is wrong - please correct me.

First, we are creating an `int` variable called `idx`. We assign it the current value of `ruleKey` (which is currently a string). If the string is `"type"`, we assign `idx` the value of `0`. If the string is `"color"`, we assign `idx` the value of `1`. If NEITHER of those two conditions pass, we assign `idx` the value of `2`.

I don't know why `res = 0` is even in the code, and I have no clue what is going on with the line of code that lies beneath. Especially with the `[&](const auto &i)` portion of the code.

Answer (score 5):

> I will try and say what I think is going on, if anything is wrong - please correct me.

Your understanding of the `idx` variable is correct.

> I don't know why `res = 0` is even in the code

It is simply declaring an unused variable `res` initialized to 0. Multiple variables of the same type can be declared in the same expression, eg:

```cpp
int a = 0, b = 1;
```

In this case, yes `res` doesn't really belong and can safely be removed.

> I have no clue what is going on with the line of code that lies beneath. Especially with the `[&](const auto &i)` portion of the code.

See the documentation for the [`std::count_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) algorithm and [Lambda Expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

In a nutshell, `std::count_if()` loops through a range, calling a predicate for each element, and increments the result each time the predicate returns `true`.  The code is using a lambda, ie an anonymous function type, for that predicate.

So, the code is iterating the `items` vector, counting how many of its inner vector elements have a value matching `ruleValue` at the index specified by `idx`.  The code is basically equivalent to this:

```
int countMatches(vector<vector<string>>& items, string ruleKey, string ruleValue) {
    int idx;
    if (ruleKey == "type") idx = 0;
    else if (ruleKey == "color") idx = 1;
    else idx = 2;

    int count = 0;
    for(auto iter = items.begin(), end = items.end(); iter != end; ++iter) {
        const auto &i = *iter;
        if (i[idx] == ruleValue) ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Maybe stronger than “is basically equivalent to:” “should be rewritten as.” :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef `?:` operator with proper indent is also easy to read. And why not use `std::count_if()`.

Comment: @templatetypedef I agree that the nested ternary operator is disgusting and should be replaced with the if/else. However, I think the `std::count_if()` with the lambda is perfectly understandable if you have sufficient knowledge of the language.

Comment: @mgonnav Yeah, `count_if` is fine here. (Confession time: I read the answer too quickly and didn't realize it was switched out. ^_^)